# Your package.json file is missing a build property inside the scripts property

Tags: node.js, express, backend, vercel

I'm deploying my api with `Vercel CLI`, and when I run `vercel dev` I get this message:

```
Error: Your package.json file is missing a build property inside the scripts property.
```

Indeed, in my `package.json` I don't have the build field, so my question is: what should it go there?